# Exception thrown at 0x0F8AD4EC (ucrtbased.dll)

Tags: c

[this window jumps when it gets to receiving a code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26iec.png)

hey, i started learing C today and made a program, i got this message on my program so i tested the exercise answer and it was getting the same error, getting the message on the picture whenever it gets to the line :
*this code is the answer ..*

```
scanf_s("%s", &id);
**thats the full code:**

int main() {
    char id[10];
    int hour;
    double value, salary;
    printf("Input the Employees ID(Max. 10 chars): ");
    scanf_s("%s", &id);
    printf("\nInput the working hrs: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &hour);
    printf("\nSalary amount/hr: ");
    scanf_s("%lf", &value);
    salary = value * hour;
    printf("\nEmployees ID = %s\nSalary = U$ %.2lf\n", id, salary);
    return 0;
}
```

didnt find any answer to it online , help please.

Comment: I would suggest reading the documentation of [`scanf_s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2017) before using it. You're missing a parameter, and need to specify the expected buffer count in the format string.

Comment: `char id[10];` can't hold 10 chars

Comment: Also relevant are the [Uninitialized memory patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/370362/332733).

Comment: the code wont compile when using "scanf" , VS17 wont let me because its "not secured" but youre saying that the problem is in the scanf_s ?

Comment: @omerperetz I'm saying that the documentation to `scanf_s` indicates you're not using it correctly. I'd highly suggest looking at the documentation if you intend to use a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: you using windows library, your program should be portable so change `scanf_s` -> `scanf` and make sure you include `stdio.h`.

Second error is here:

```
scanf_s("%s", &id);
```

Should be

```
scanf_s("%s", id);
```

Because function want argument `char*`, in first example you pass `&(char[]) => char**`.